# How to upload an AviSynth video to Youtube?

Tags: youtube, avidemux, avisynth

I already found a way, but I would like to know how to do it right and fast

That's how I do:

1. Open the script into Avisynth Proxy
2. Start the proxy and Avidemux
3. Save the video to a file
4. Upload the file to Youtube

Problems:

1. it's too cumbersome
2. I only could generate uncompressed files so far

Comment: Besides actually encoding the video into a format Youtube recognizes, you can't.  You could use something like MeGUI or AviDemux to encode the video into an MP4 and then upload it.

Comment: @Breakthrough if MeGUI is easier than AviDemux than you should post it as an answer

Comment: I believe it would be the same difficulty level... Just set the output video type to x264, whatever audio format you want (AAC), and the container to .mp4.  There should be some presets to get you started, or you can follow Youtube's guidelines for video uploading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AviSynth forum

http://forum.doom9.org/showthread.php?t=160639

recommended Mediacoder

http://www.mediacoderhq.com/

I tested it and it worked